# Who are the key individuals in Canada's Old Age Security program?

Tags: taxes, budget, canada, social-security

I am a student doing a project on the Old Age Security (OAS) program for Civic Studies 11. I have tried researching important individuals involved in this program, but could not find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean individual who are important in causing the program to be enacted or individuals who are important in administering the program today?